# Regex (Bigquery) get specific values from STRING

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I have the STRING - `TX1234XT batch 44, 1111ABCDEF`

- TX1234XT (Can be different length)
- batch 44 (number can be different length)
- ABCDEF (can be a different length, but always have 1111 at the start)

What I need is to generate two columns:

```
BatchNumber    Name
    44         1111ABCDEF
    1          1111SAMPLE
    999        1111Example
```

Starting point:

First is done:

- `REGEXP_EXTRACT(reference, r'1111[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+') AS Name`

Second 
- `REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(reference, r'batch [0-9_.+-]+'),r'batch ','') AS BatchNumber`

SORTED ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know Google Big Query, but if you want to extract the batch number and the value at the end, you could go with this regular expression:

```regex
/^.*?batch\s*(\d+),\s*(1111.+)$/
```

- `(\d+)` will capture your batch id.
- `(1111.+)` will capture the value starting with 1111.

Example here: https://regex101.com/r/SJXmIV/2